# Vaadin Flow 14, Jetty embedded and static files

Tags: jar, classloader, embedded-jetty, vaadin-flow

I'm trying to create app based on Jetty 9.4.20 (embedded) and Vaadin Flow 14.0.12.

It based on very nice project [vaadin14-embedded-jetty](https://github.com/mvysny/vaadin14-embedded-jetty).

I want to package app with one `main-jar` and all dependency libs must be in folder 'libs' near `main-jar`.

I remove `maven-assembly-plugin`, instead use `maven-dependency-plugin` and `maven-jar-plugin`. In `maven-dependency-plugin` i add section `<execution>get-dependencies</execution>` where i unpack directories `META-INF/resources/,META-INF/services/` from Vaadin Flow libs to the result JAR.

In this case app work fine. But if i comment section `<execution>get-dependencies</execution>` then result package didn't contain that directories and app didn't work.

It just cannot give some static files from Vaadin Flow libs.

This error occurs only if i launch packaged app with ...

```
$ java -jar vaadin14-embedded-jetty-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

... but from Intellij Idea it launch correctly.

There was an opinion that is Jetty staring with wrong ClassLoader and cannot maintain requests to static files in Jar-libs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `META-INF/services/` files MUST be maintained from the Jetty libs.

That's important for Jetty to use `java.util.ServiceLoader`.

If you are merging contents of JAR files into a single JAR file, that's called a "uber jar".

There are many techniques to do this, but if you are using `maven-assembly-plugin` or `maven-dependency-plugin` to build this "uber jar" then you will not be merging critical files that have the same name across multiple JAR files.

Consider using `maven-shade-plugin` and it's associated Resource Transformers to properly merge these files.

- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/
- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html

The `ServicesResourceTransformer` is the one that merges `META-INF/services/` files, use it.

As for static content, that works fine, but you have to setup your Base Resource properly.

Looking at your source, you do the following ...

```java
final URI webRootUri = ManualJetty.class.getResource("/webapp/").toURI();
final WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(webRootUri));
```

That won't work reliably in 100% of cases (as you have noticed when running in the IDE vs command line).

The `Class.getResource(String)` is only reliable if you lookup a file (not a directory).

Consider that the [Jetty Project Embedded Cookbook](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/) recipes have techniques for this.

See:

- [WebAppContextFromClasspath.java](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/WebAppContextFromClasspath.java)
- [ResourceHandlerFromClasspath.java](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/ResourceHandlerFromClasspath.java)
- [DefaultServletFileServer.java](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/DefaultServletFileServer.java)
- [DefaultServletMultipleBases.java](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/DefaultServletMultipleBases.java)
- [XmlEnhancedServer.java](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/XmlEnhancedServer.java)
- [MultipartMimeUploadExample.java](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/MultipartMimeUploadExample.java)

Example:

```java
// Figure out what path to serve content from
ClassLoader cl = ManualJetty.class.getClassLoader();
// We look for a file, as ClassLoader.getResource() is not
// designed to look for directories (we resolve the directory later)
URL f = cl.getResource("webapp/index.html");
if (f == null)
{
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find resource directory");
}

// Resolve file to directory
URI webRootUri = f.toURI().resolve("./").normalize();
System.err.println("WebRoot is " + webRootUri);

WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(webRootUri));
```

Comment: I have created [fork](https://github.com/lanmaster/vaadin14-embedded-jetty) from last version of Martin's repo, where replace maven assembly to shade plugin. Working good. Thanks.